# How to read&Run Multiple variables from bufferedreader in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, bufferedreader

Before I had these two variables (a),(total) in two different class but I couldnt get the properties of the class.

So,

I tried to put both the code into a single class 
but neither one of the variable is working
`System.out.println("( "+file1.getName() +" )-" +" Total no of words=" + a +"Total repeated words counted:"+total);`

Neither one is working:

My present sample output so far:

( Blog 39.txt )-Total repeated words counted:4,total no of words:0

neither

( Blog 39.txt )-Total repeated words counted:0,total no of words:82

The output which i needed is:

( Blog 39.txt )-Total repeated words counted:4,total no of words:82

When I run neither "a" or "total" is working.(vice versa) If i change the code (variable)order.

Anyone tell how should I get both the variable output??
:)
I am a beginner to java

Here is my code below.

```
package ramki;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class newrepeatedcount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.endsWith(".txt");
            }
        };
        File folder = new File("E:\\testfolder\\");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(filter);
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            File file1 = listOfFiles[i];

            BufferedReader ins = null;
            try {
                ins = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file1)));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String line = "", str = "";
            String st = null;
            try {
                st = IOUtils.toString(ins);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // split text to array of words
            String[] words = st.split("\\s");
            // frequency array
            int[] fr = new int[words.length];
            // init frequency array
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < fr.length; i1++)
                fr[i1] = -1;
            // count words frequency
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < words.length; i1++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                    if (words[i1].equals(words[j])) {
                        fr[i1]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            // clean duplicates
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < words.length; i1++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                    if (words[i1].equals(words[j])) {
                        if (i1 != j)
                            words[i1] = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            int a = 0;
            try {
                while ((line = ins.readLine()) != null) {
                    str += line + " ";
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(str);
            while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String s = st1.nextToken();
                a++;
            }
            int total = 0;
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < words.length; i1++) {
                if (words[i1] != "") {
                    // System.out.println(words[i1]+"="+fr[i1]);
                    total += fr[i1];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("( " + file1.getName() + " )-"
                    + "Total repeated words counted:" + total + ","
                    + "total no of words:" + a);
            // System.out.println("total no of words:"+a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you a) fix your formatting b) when you catch an IOException don't pretend it didn't happen and continue, you should only catch an exception where you can add some value.

Comment: Why do you read the content of the file and then discard it and read it again?  Then you split the words, but later use StringTokenizer on the words combined. I suggest you clean up this code and remove stuff which isn't useful so you can easily see what the problem is when you debug the code in your debugger.

Comment: Now you can see my edited code:

Comment: You are reading the file twice, two different ways.  You should only read the file once, partly because this is more efficient but mostly because once you have read all the data, you can't read anything after it. This is why your second loop never reads anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read a stream to its end, you will not be able to read any further.
As your code is not optimized in many ways, i can suggeest a quick and dirty way to make your code work. Just initialize the BufferedReader that is assigned to the variable "ins", before you calculate the value of "a" anew.

```
...
try {
    ins = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file1)));
    while ((line = ins.readLine()) != null) {
        str += line + " ";
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
...
```

Comment: I did this before but now It is not calculating "total" value.

Comment: Just as a disclaimer: There are tons of things, that could and should be changed about your code. My provided change is not what i would ultimately recommend, but it would make your code work.

Comment: "Works on my machine". No, honestly: I see no reason, why it would not calculate "total" with my suggestion and in fact, it prints it on my machine.

Comment: before your suggestion I had ( Blog 39.txt )-Total repeated words counted:4,total no of words:0.After your suggestion I got this ( Blog 39.txt )-Total repeated words counted:0,total no of words:82 . It shows 0. :/

Comment: Please create a text file that contains "a b c a b". I get ( test.txt )-Total repeated words counted:2,total no of words:5

Comment: I did but sitll i get the count as 0 for ""total"" My text file has repeated words:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101857/discussion-between-ram-ki-and-realsim).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the best solution but this will give you a Set or Map(Internally you can convert and number of times it has appeared in your text. Then you can use it based on your requirement.

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

 public class NewRepeatedCount  {

    public static void main(String... arg0)
    {
     BufferedReader br = null;
     Map<String, Integer> counterMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] words = sCurrentLine.split("\\s");
                for(String word : words)
                {
                    int count = 1;
                    if(counterMap.get(word) != null)
                    {
                        count = counterMap.get(word);
                        count++;
                        counterMap.put(word, count);
                    }else{
                        counterMap.put(word, count);
                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.println(counterMap.entrySet());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have data processing like this, Java 8's Stream API is likely to be the best choice.

```
// get all the files under this folder
Files.walk(Paths.get("E:\\testfolder\\"))
        // keep all the files ending in .txt
        .filter(p -> p.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt"))
        .forEach(p -> {
            try {
                // process all the lines of the file.
                Map<String, Long> wordCount = Files.lines(p)
                        // break the lines into words
                        .flatMap(l -> Stream.of(l.split("\\s")))
                        // collect the words and count them
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting()));
                // find how many values are more than 1
                long wordDuplicates = wordCount.values().stream().filter(l -> l > 1).count();
                // get the sum of all the values.
                long totalWords = wordCount.values().stream().mapToLong(l -> l).sum();
                System.out.println(p + " has " + wordDuplicates + " duplicates and " + totalWords + " words");
            // catch the IOException at the end because you can't do anything more with the file if this happens.
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```